# Verilog Uknowns

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module subtractor(out,x,y);
  output [31:0]out;
  input [31:0]x,y;
  wire c_out,c_dummy;
  wire [31:0]sum1,sum2,sum3,y_c;
  reg c_in;

  ones_complement oc0(y_c,y);
  thirtytwo_bit_fa thirtytwo_fa0(c_out,sum1,c_in,x,y_c);
  thirtytwo_bit_fa thirtytwo_fa1(c_dummy,sum2,c_in,sum1,c_out);
  thirtytwo_bit_fa thirtytwo_fa2(c_dummy,sum3,c_in,sum2,{32{~c_out}});

  initial
    begin
      #1 c_in=0;
      $display("%b",c_out);
    end

  assign out=c_out?sum1:-sum1;
endmodule
```

So i wrote this simple 32-bit subtractor module..The problem is that the output of c_out is always turning out to be 'x' and hence the entire outputis 'xxxxxxxx...'..What am i doing wrong? Note:All the modules seperately is perfectly working just fine...like the ones complement and the full adder...working fine.

Comment: if `thirtytwo_bit_fa` is know to be working then my guess is `$display` is issued to soon. Add a `#1` before it or change it to `$strobe` and let us know if that changed anything.

Comment: how do you know that separate modules were working. This is  a strange model all together. There is no clock nor reset. All values are initialized to 'x' by verilog, so your module does not update it. What is it in any case?

Comment: All values will be `x` bydefault in the starting. You can use the `bit` datatype, to make it `0` in the starting. But ideally that should not be used, and you should have some reset condition to start your system.

Answer (score 2):

You're checking an output while simultaneously changing an input signal. Switch the assignment of c_in and the delay. I presume that you mean for c_in to have a value when the system starts.

```
initial
  begin
    c_in=0;
    #1;
    $display("%b",c_out);
  end
```

Be careful when tweaking inputs and checking outputs. Whenever you change the value of a signal, you must wait for the change to propagate through the rest of the system before checking the outputs.

However, since it appears that c_in is only used in this system as a constant, I suggest that you look into using a localparam or some constant value in c_in's place. For example:

```
localparam c_in_zero = 1'b0;

thirtytwo_bit_fa thirtytwo_fa0(c_out,sum1,c_in_zero,x,y_c);
```